# How to set size mapping based on a variable?

Tags: r

I am using r to graph a scatterplot based on the Cars93 dataset.

I am asked to:

Define a `ggplot` object using the Cars93 data set that you can use to view `Price` on the y-axis, `MPG.highway` on the x-axis, and set the `size` mapping to be based on `Horsepower`.

Use `geom_point()` to create a scatterplot from your `ggplot` object.

I do not understand what it means to set the size mapping to based on Horsepower? Size is not a variable of Cars93.

```
data("Cars93")
ggplot(Cars93, mapping=aes(MPG.highway, Price)) + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it means to plot `size` based on `Horsepower` values

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Cars93, aes(MPG.highway, Price, size = Horsepower)) + geom_point()
```

[image]